# Is there and Alternative for Scheduling notification(push) and tasks jobs in .NET except using job scheduler?

Tags: c#, .net

we're currently scheduling jobs with quartz scheduler but we need to avoid job scheduling as it will be resource consuming if there are 1000 of jobs ,any suggestion alternative would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have 1000 jobs, it will consume resources no matter how you run them.

Answer (score 1):

The most common variant (and in my humble opinion) the best one is to use a job scheduler like Quartz.NET. Scheduling is hard, despite the fact that it seems to be obvious for our human brains most of the time.

That said, I have seen solutions where classes are instantiated and methods called that are actually infinite loops waiting for their time again and again. The main burdens here are parallel execution of jobs (thread handling, etc) as well as error handling (eg one unhandled exception in one of you classes might well crash your complete system, something that scheduling libraries usually handle at a high level).

If resources are a problem I would recommend to use a scheduler which may be horizontally scaled (I do not know about Quartz but if I remember correctly this is possible with Hangfire).

Comment: Sascha - what do you mean by horizontally scaled?

Comment: Horizontally as in the ability to add more instances. So if you can run as many instances of your scheduler (on different servers) without having jobs run n times you can have a scheduler with literally an infinite amount of jobs (maybe just limited by the money you can spent on resources)